# How can I compare two curves statistically?

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-geometry, algebraic-curves

I have points in a 2D space, and each point has X and Y coordinate. These points are stored in an array. There are two separate arrays each array has n points with X and Y coordinate. The points in those arrays represent two curves, i.e. the first array represent the 1st curve and second array represents the 2nd curve. I want to compare those two curves statistically, or with some measure, for example, the circle is measured with radius, line with a length, etc. likewise I want to compare those curves with that kind of characteristic which can be represented by just one number.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange! A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). For typesetting, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @dantopa Thank you for your information. I'm first time using this for mathematics. I'll make sure next time when I have equations and some mathematical formulations, but at this point I just have some points in 2D space and I need help for getting some measure for the curve.

Comment: You seem to be asking two seperate questions: 1) How can you parametrize these curves ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curve_fitting ) 2) How can you measure the difference between curves ( here is one choice: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/31922-discrete-frechet-distance )